# How to determine if a file with a trailing space exists?

Tags: powershell, path

I need a script to iterate over directories, find if a file with a trailing space exists, log that it exists if it does, then rename the file.  I am stuck on the most important part:  finding if a file exists.

The normal method for determining if a file exists is

`Test-Path -Path somepath`

However, that does not work if you need to test if a file with a trailing space exists.  When given a known path `somepath`  to a file that has a trailing space in the filename, all these  fail:

`Test-Path -Path somepath` 
`Test-Path -Path 'somepath '`
`Test-Path -Path "somepath "`
`Test-Path -LiteralPath somepath` 
`Test-Path -LiteralPath 'somepath '`
`Test-Path -LiteralPath "somepath "`

How does Powershell test for files with spaces in the name?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's a regular space and not a different character that happens to look like a regular space?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem isn't Powershell - it's Windows.  However, Windows does have a way to force a literal string:  prepend `\\?\` to a path:

> For file I/O, the "`\\?\`" prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the MAX_PATH limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs.

I found this in the Windows path documentation [at the Microsoft Docs site.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)  Changing `somepath` to include `\\?\` at the beginning made PowerShell behave as expected with strings with trailing spaces.

Comment: Sorry to ask then answer but I legitimately thought this was an edge case in Powershell.  Nope, my assumptions about paths were incorrect.